# Cant get values of checkboxes in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox

Im trying to insert multiple checkboxes but cant get their values in codeigniter 2

this is my code in **View**

```
   <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkboxes-0" value="22">
                          Пентхаус
                        </label>
                          <br>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                      <input id="cena" name="cena[]" type="text" placeholder="Въведи цена" class="form-control input-md">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkboxes-1" value="21">
                          Гараж/Паркомясто
                        </label>
                    <br>
                                            <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                      <input id="cena" name="cena[]" type="text" placeholder="Въведи цена" class="form-control input-md">

                      </div>
                    </div>
```

This is my Model:

```
    public function InsertCheckbox() {

           $property_typesRequest = $this->input->post('checkboxes');
            foreach($property_typesRequest as $value){
            $this->db->insert_batch('property_type_details', $property_typesRequest);

            }

}
```

in Controller i just use this:

```
        $this->estate_m->InsertCheckbox();
```

And this going insert 0 in database, when i var_dump  $property_typesRequest theres shows bool(false). I cant get values of checkboxes...

**EDIT...**

I have try to edit my code but still no result:

```
  public function edit()/*this is  controller */
{  
    $data=array('column_name'=>$this->input->post('checkboxes');
    $result=$this->estate_m->InsertCheckbox($data);
    if($result==true)
    {
            echo "Success";
    }
    else
    {
            echo "Fail";
    }

}
public function InsertCheckbox($data) /*this is Model */
    {    
    $this->db->insert('property_type_details', $data);
    return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1 ) ? false : true;

}
```

With this edited code always gives me Succes

Comment: have you checked/selected any checkbox before submission of form ?

Comment: remove brackes from name. And try.

Comment: What is your form method ? waht is var_dump result of this? `$this->input->post('checkboxes');`

Comment: 1.Yes i checked/selected any checkbox before submission.
2.I have tryed same result.
3.Result is bool(false) with POST method

Comment: show me the expected output format while submitting form which is saved in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Form submitted values should be in multi dimension array**
To achieve that your form inputs should be in multi dimension.

For insert_batch() function, the array should be in multi dimension.
In array every key must be field names in db table and value must be the form input value.
So change the form structure like the below array.

```
array(
   array(
     'checkboxes' => 'checkboxe value' ,
     'cena' => 'cena values'
   ),
   array(
     'checkboxes' => 'checkboxe value' ,
     'cena' => 'cena values'
   )
);
```

Form inputs should be like below:

```
<input name="data[1][checkbox_columnname]" type="checkbox" value="21">Пентхаус
<input name="data[1][textbox_columnname]" type="text">

<input name="data[2][checkbox_columnname]" type="checkbox" value="22">Гараж/Паркомясто
<input name="data[2][textbox_columnname]" type="text">
```

And the model should not have foreach loop.
Simply pass the data as below.

```
$data=$this->input->post('data');

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: Yes i know that, for that i make name="checkboxes[]" to make them Multidimension , but problem is that somehow i cant get them into array

Comment: I dont get which output you want in last coment i say i get bool(false) which iz 0 and inserting 0

Comment: CREATE TABLE `property_type_details` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `property_id` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `property_type_id` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `alt_txt` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `property_id` (`property_id`),
  KEY `property_type_id` (`property_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer and i have try it but still bool(false) and still inserting 0 is theres a need change something in controler or  just         $this->estate_m->InsertCheckbox();
 is ok? ?

Comment: I have get your code and with some modify i succes to insert some values but with values is inserting some 0 with it how to get rid of them?

Comment: you are not selected some check-boxes or all. In db for empty check box 0 will set.

Comment: i check all checkboxes and its insert one 0 per checkbox if i check 2 checkboxes inserting two zeros if i check only 1 checkbox is insert only one 0

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code in model.

```
 public function InsertCheckbox() {

            $property_typesRequest = $this->input->post('checkboxes');
            foreach($property_typesRequest as $value){
              $data['columnename'] = $value;
              $this->db->insert('tablename', $data); 
            }

}
```

Hope it inserts into the database

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i have try this before , the problem is that is cuz $property_typesRequest  is not come in array, and for that when i forech them $value become NULL :(